# What topics are important to analyse a financial product?

Tags: finance, markets, financial-markets, stock-market, corporate-finance

When reading analysis papers of financial product, derivative or stock, tangible or not, I noticed that a lot of those papers seem to have similar structures.

This got me to the question if there exists some sort a basis structure to use when analysing a financial product. Or if there are some important topics we need to take in account, to have our analysis accepted by the Financial and Economic communities?

***Please note that I'm referring to research/analysis that focuses on the financial product.***

***Edit - 2015/05/29:*** As commented: I'm interested in doing a theoretical analysis of, for example, a derivative that someone invented, this won't have any historical data.
Also, what is analysed when a central bank receives a proposal for a new product (i.e. new type of derivative)? What type of analysis is done? It's more in this sense, analysing a new formulation of a financial product that isn't on the market yet. How is this done?

Comment: This is very broad. If you are looking to publish a paper, it takes decades of training, and a doctorate, usually.  Usually your advisor will be able to transmit this tacit knowledge to you, choose him/her carefully.

Comment: I'm interested in doing a theoretical analysis of, for example, a derivative that someone invented, this won't have any historical data.

Comment: Your question might be more suited to http://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a very good question - there may not be an answer.  Afaik, central banks don't receive proposals for arbitrary financial instruments - they probably should. They may have to pass muster by a regulatory authority, but quite often the main criteria is simply, can the inventor find a buyer. One example that may be interesting is hybrid capital for the purposes of meeting the Basel Tier requirement - there is a history of instruments being invented for this, and then being rejected by the central banks a few months later.

Comment: As far as I know the português central bank (Banco de Portugal) receives financial instruments to approve. But in most cases you're right, they don't. I would like to develop a new financial instrument, and would like to analyse it before its presentation... :-/

Comment: Is it specifically for banks, or for trading? The basel capital tiers have very specific requirements for the instruments that can be used there.

Comment: Well both. I want to analyse a newly developed instrument that's not in the market yet.

Comment: How were all those other instruments analysed before they put it on the market?